# Expand <ul> when <li> class = active

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscript

I have jscript that expands an unordered list on click. A separate jscript uses PreziPlayer to jump to a specific path point in a prezi when a li link is clicked. This works fine, but I am struggling with getting the list to expand when the prezi is moved forward.

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/decker2/33t7y/2

Steps to replicate in jsFiddle file:

1. In Results click a triangle to expand the list.
2. Click a link item, you will see the prezi on the left jump to a different path point.
3. On the prezi player click forward or back button. The corresponding
   list item will highlight in blue, but you won't see this if the list
   item is in a sub menu, so I need the sub menu to expand.

I have tried jquery relevant code snippet is below:

```
    player.on(PreziPlayer.EVENT_CURRENT_STEP, function(e) {
        $('#treemenu1 li').removeClass('active');
        $('#treemenu1 li a[href=#'+e.value+']').parent().addClass('active');
        $('#treemenu1').find('li:has(ul)')
         $('#treemenu1 ul').children('ul').toggle('medium');**
```

Comment: Please consider including a jsFiddle. That will make it easier for us to help you and will increase your chance of getting a reply.

Comment: Improving on chopper's advise; consider putting up a ***reduced test case*** instead of copy pasting the bulk of your code.

Comment: jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/decker2/33t7y/1/